# tableview cell in xib can't autosize

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xib, autosize

here need some help T_T.

I'm design a page that use a collection View to display 4 different table view in 4 collection view cell. Therefore I design collection view in xib and put a table view in it, but in this case tableview have no prototype cell when it is designed in a collection view cell in xib , so I create another xib to handle my tableview cell.

The problem is , when Im adding "estimatedRowHeight" and "AutomaticDimension" in cellForRowAt below

```
let backgroundCell = detailCellTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "baseDetailTableViewCell") as! BaseDetailTableViewCell

backgroundCell.setTitleLabelText(title: backgroundTitle)
backgroundCell.setContentLabelText(content: background)

self.detailCellTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
self.detailCellTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

return backgroundCell
```

it would be none change tvcell
[image: none change tvcell]

The cell size won't autosizing , the label in my custom cell is stacked.

I guess that the problem might be the prototype cell , but I don't know how to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

This is because, this property is added to the tableview and you are adding it to cell.

Steps:

1) Create a tableview outlet.

2) add following code in viewdidload()

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

Comment: thanks , but I did added it to my tableview . I just call it when create cell in cellForRowAt.

Comment: I don't Know why it doesnt work in cellforrowatindexpath. It works properly in viewdidload